# Bug no layout do Stack Snippet, o botão fica sobreposto

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Hoje ao usar o *stack snippet* notei que o botão de fullscreen fica por cima do botão "Esconder":

> [image: satck snippet]

Este problema ocorre somente quando o botão "Copiar trecho de código para a resposta" está habilitado.

Note que não ocorre no SOen, ou seja o problema é devido aos textos longos:

> [image: Stack snippet no SOen]

Exemplo de lugar com problema: [Boas práticas de CSS para Height responsivo. É armengue ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/144291/3635)

### Atualização

No [transifex](/questions/tagged/transifex) foi apenas a sugestão do @Bacco, faltou o "Executar trecho de código" => "Executar código" (ou "Executar"), pois ainda afeta um pouco a funcionalidade:

> [image: Executar trecho de código]

Answer (score 8):

Sugiro simplificar os textos para algo como:

### Sugestão 1:

Acho que "trecho" é desnecessário, assim como "Esconder resultado", então sugiro:

- <kbd>Executar trecho de código</kbd> => <kbd>Executar código</kbd>
- <kbd>Esconder resultado</kbd> => <kbd>Esconder</kbd>

> [image: sugestão para stack snippet]

### Sugestão 2:

Acho que código está implícito, o que poderia tornar mais simples ainda:

- <kbd>Executar trecho de código</kbd> => <kbd>Executar</kbd>
- <kbd>Esconder resultado</kbd> => <kbd>Esconder</kbd>

> [image: sugestão 2]

### Sugestão adicional:

Sugerido pelo @Bacco, isto pode ser usado junto a sugestão 1 ou 2, é apenas pra deixar o texto mais intuitivo do botão "copiar":

> [image: Sugestão para deixar o botão mais intuitivo]

Comment: Pensando bem, algo do tipo "Copiar para uma nova resposta" talvez seja melhor, pois se não me engano, mesmo se você já tem uma resposta em edição, uma nova será criada. Se alguém puder confirmar, melhor :)

Comment: @Bacco sim e mesmo que vc não tenha resposta, ainda sim fica mais intuitivo e servirá pra todos casos, vou editar.

Comment: Teste antes... usei isso uma ou 2x na vida só, e faz tempo :)

Comment: @Bacco fiz o teste mais cedo, nesta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/144291/3635

Comment: Usei a pouco e notei esse bug, gostei da sugestão.

Comment: Usei a sugestão do @Bacco pra string. Vai pro ar quando houver um novo build. Se consertar, me avise que eu marco como resolvido.

Comment: @Gabe faltou o "executar trecho" => http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx0Ea.png . Veja que ainda sobrepõe. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Cortei só pra "executar" e "esconder". Valeu pelo aviso.

Comment: @Gabe se conseguir um tempo livre vou tentar entender o transfix e ver como posso colaborar ;)

Comment: @Gabe só tenho que dizer obrigado por tudo, mas me desculpe incomoda-lo novamente, é que não entendi bem uma coisa, o botão "esconder" continua "esconder resultado", no caso da maneira que está funcionando, mas notei que isso não mudou, então só estou relatando: http://i.stack.imgur.com/di1Iw.png todavia mudando ou não este botão, já está funcionando e ao meu ver já esta pronto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então, eu *suspeito* que está tendo um teste A/B com o Stack Snippet, e nós não estamos vendo as mesmas versões... Porque as strings usadas tão diferentes.

Comment: @Gabe testei aqui em modo privativo, não é cache do navegador, pode ser algum cache no servidor, talvez a versão da build varie pra ti se comparado aos demais usuários.